# Wordpress PHP-exec header problem

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I am trying to integrate one of my websites with facebook connect.

I have developed the code and it works as expected.

I want to integrate the code into a wordpress page utilizing the php-exec plugin to parse php.

When i do as can be seen at gua.com/testing it simply does not work. Seemingly the session etc is registered but it simply displays the connect box again..

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your code use global variables?  Php-exec works using eval() and eval() has different rules for globals.

But I've got more ideas...

There are a few different versions of the facebook connect api, but all of the ones I've used used also required a lump of javascript to be included in the site, I don't see that on your page.  Make sure it isn't needed.

If that's not the problem, try including the facebook lib in wp-config.php, then call it from php-exec.  I'm not really sure if that'll work or not but it's worth a shot.

Comment: No the variables are all local... apart from anything withing the PHP-SDK... but that is the point where it starts to go over my head.. Cheers